# Hidden SPAM script in Joomla footer

Tags: joomla, footer, spam

I got my `Joomla` site `www.semignu.dk` and there is suddenly some hidden SPAM script in my footer? How do I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the following code:

```
//<!--
document.getElementById('cloak6482').innerHTML = '';
var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
var addy6482 = 'K&#111;nt&#97;kt' + '&#64;';
addy6482 = addy6482 + 's&#101;m&#105;gn&#117;' + '&#46;' + 'dk';
var addy_text6482 = 'K&#111;nt&#97;kt' + '&#64;' + 's&#101;m&#105;gn&#117;' + '&#46;' + 'dk';
document.getElementById('cloak6482').innerHTML += '<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addy6482 + '\'>'+addy_text6482+'<\/a>';
//-->
```

Then this is not spam. It's part of the email cloaking that you possibly have turned on.

Open the footer module in the Joomla Module Manager and look for:

```
{emailcloak=on}
```